# Canvas getImageData and putImageData load image partially

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my code. I am uploading a image and using like this :

```
> var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
> var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
> context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

This works fine but if I copy the imagedata like below to another canvas. It loads image partially.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
context1.putImageData(context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height), 0, 0);
```

I tried same approach by creating two canvas and this code which worked fine but without image.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

var d = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
var btx = d.getContext('2d');
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 300);
btx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

If i create two canvas it works fine but not like the above where I am using in memory canvas.

My HTML file has this :

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="960" height="960"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="960" height="960"></canvas>
```

Comment: if you create canvases you need to set their width and height manually within code

Comment: @MysterX I have edited the question and added html file content. Thanks for the response. I got my mistake.

Comment: @MysterX can you add that as answer it worked. So i can accept it. Adding height and width to canvas worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create canvases, you need to set their width manually. Default canvas size is 300x150. From here [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement).
Something like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy one canvas to another use `drawImage` rather than `getImageData`, `setImageData` That way you will use the GPU to move the pixels rather than the CPU. You also have the option to resize, crop, and apply a variety of FXs.

```
// create a copy of canvasSource 
// returns the newly created canvas.
function copyCanvas(canvasSource){
    var canvasCopy = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvasCopy.width = canvasSource.width;
    canvasCopy.height = canvasSource.height;
    canvasCopy.getContext("2d").drawImage(canvasSource, 0, 0);
    return canvasCopy;
}
```